# Using Buttons like radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have the user choose between a set of choices, but rather than a list of radio buttons and descriptions i'd like buttons which have the descriptions on the buttons (looks better and less ambiguous). But there would also be preferably some way to know what the group of buttons is "set" to. This is to make it work just like the radio buttons would.

Is there a standard way to do this? I'd like to be able to guarantee that the currently selected option will be easily identifiable (assigning colors manually if I must do it that way).

What I'm not sure about at the moment is if it'll work (on most browsers) if I just try to assign multiple buttons with the same `name`, like I would do with the radio buttons.

Comment: I'd rather just mash radio buttons. They're semantically correct, and hardly ambiguous when you've got a label next to them.

Comment: No, there is no _standard_ way of doing this. The _standard_ way is to **use radio buttons.**

Comment: @Matt, Radio buttons take sometimes much more space than buttons, and are harder to scan quickly. Steven, We use toggle buttons like you describe in our web app. But we programmed the behavior, it is easy.

Comment: @Mic, do you spam id's or classes to do it? I'd do that and call it a day but I just know it's going to be a pain to debug later. I guess I can just make a convention and use a class called "selected". Not quite nasty enough to be considered spam i guess.

Comment: @JamWaffles I have a densely packed table that contains lots of settings. I would have 3 radio buttons side by side, and it isn't immediately clear which label is assigned to which button, plus it just looks bad. I could stack them vertically but it wouldn't fit well into the table.

Comment: @steven, there is a "_current" class, that is set to the current button

Comment: to follow up on this, i determined radio buttons to be too fugly and went for this. `<input type="button" name="right" value="&rarr;" class="button_movement" onclick='removeBtnSiblingsEnabled(this); this.setAttribute("class","button_movement selected");' />` `removeBtnSiblingsEnabled` resets the button's siblings' classes to `button_movement`. (i needed that for formatting these buttons) and the `selected` class makes it look selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use labels to extend the click area of a radio button.

```
<label class="radioLabel"><input type="radio" value="0" /> None</label>
```

Now, style the label to make it look like a button. To give the label other visuals, such as mouseover/inactive/selected, use javascript to add/remove classes to the label and subscribe to mouse events (hover, click etc)

You can hide the radio buttons with CSS, but unless you have images to set as backgrounds for the various states (inactive/selected/mouseover), I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Why use JavaScript to add/remove classes to the labels when you can just use `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus`, ... directly in CSS?

Comment: Because they are not supported in older browsers.

Comment: `:hover` is supported on every element since IE7. We're talking about 96.91% of internet users supporting it, based on the latest StatCounter data.

Answer (score 2):

Visual display is an issue for CSS and HTML. The label can be associated with the radio button by having a box border around both to group them visually. A slight change of background colour will help too. To pack them close together, put the button under the label. It shouldn't take up any more room than a button and you save a slab of script.

Like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.aButton {
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 1px;
}
</style>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="aButton" for="b0">Yes<input type="radio" name="group1" id="b0"></label>
        <label class="aButton" for="b1">No<input type="radio" name="group1" id="b1"></label>
        <label class="aButton" for="b2">Maybe<input type="radio" name="group1" id="b2"></label>
</table>
```

Comment: Good answer. FYI, if the label is surrounding the input, you don't need the `for` attribute.

Comment: According to the spec, no. But iE 6, 7 and probably 8 require the *for* attribute even if the control is inside the label.

Comment: Yes, both answers are very good. Wish i could accept both. I came up with a good way to make use of the radio buttons, and will probably use a border to group them.

Comment: @RobG You're right! IE6 what a nightmare to deal with. We've dropped support for it in our company.